# Can QSignalMapper be used to re-emit signals with multiple parameters?

Tags: qt

Is it possible to use QSignalMapper to re-emit signals with multiple parameters?  I have found a workaround but im curious to know if it is possible.

example: take
 void QLineEdit::textEdited ( const QString & text )   [signal]

and re-emit:

void newSignal(int group, int pos);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`QSignalMapper` can not be used for that, but the class is quite simple to re-implement and specialize for your needs. Simply use a `QMap<QObject*,ValueStruct>`, where `ValueStruct` keeps your arguments. When you receive a signal, `map()`, look at `QObject::sender()` ([link](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qobject.html#sender)) as the key in the map to make the emit in your turn.